# Is $t_n=\frac{1}{n} \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)$ convergent?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Let $$t_n=\frac{1}{n} \left( 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \right)$$

Is the following series convergent?

---

If we let $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0\rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)=0.$$

I don't know whether this is correct or not.

Comment: There is a standard result (which you seem to indicate in your post) that if $a_{n} \to L$ as $n \to \infty$ then $\dfrac{a_{1} + a_{2} + \cdots + a_{n}}{n} \to L$ as $n \to \infty$. And you can use it here. But this is not known as Cauchy's Principle of Convergence.

Comment: if $a_n \to 0$ then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is $N_\epsilon$ such that $n \ge N_\epsilon \implies |a_n| < \epsilon$ so that $n > N_\epsilon \implies |\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{n}| \le |\sum_{k=1}^{N_\epsilon} \frac{a_k}{n}|+ |\sum_{k=N_\epsilon+1}^n \frac{a_k}{n}| <  \frac{N_\epsilon \max_n |a_n|}{n} + \epsilon \frac{n-N_\epsilon}{n}$. since $\epsilon$ and $\frac{N_\epsilon \max_n |a_n|}{n}$ are arbitrary small, it shows $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{n} \to 0$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070575/prove-that-c-n-frac1n-bigl-frac1-sqrt2-frac1-sqrt3-cdots?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\le 1+\int_1^n \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}.$$
Integrate and divide by $n$ to conclude that our sequence has limit $0$.

*Remark:* Your method is correct, but requires somewhat more machinery than the above estimate. But if that machinery is already available, it provides a computation-free proof.

Answer (score 3):

By RMS-AM,

$$\sqrt{\frac{1 + 1/2 + \dots + 1/n}{n}} \geq t_n \geq 0.$$

Since $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = O(\log n)$, we have $t_n \to 0$ by squeezing.